# Call task assembleDebug for each subproject

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I am new to gradle, please help me to figure out what I am doing wrong.

I have a bunch of apps with own working gradle build system. I created a project that contains these apps and I want to write a task that goes over all subprojects and call 'assembleDebug' for each of them.

```
Apps
- AppA
-- app
-- build.gradle
-- settings.gradle
- AppB
-- app
-- build.gradle
-- settings.gradle
```

In settings.gradle I have

```
rootProject.name = 'Apps'
include ':AppA', ':AppB'
```

In build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    task buildAll {
        doLast { task ->
            println "Building $task.project.name"
            //gradle $task.assembleDebug // also tried assembleDebug
        }
    }
}
```

When I call gradle buildAll, I can see log message

```
> Task :buildAll
Building Apps

> Task :AppA:buildAll
Building AppA

> Task :AppB:buildAll
Building AppB
```

But when I uncomment line `//gradle $task.assembleDebug`, I have error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildAll'.
> Could not get unknown property '$task' for task ':buildAll' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.
```

When I call command from root directory

```
gradle :AppA:assembleDebug
```

I see the same error.
If I call command from AppA directory everything works fine.

What is going ?
Thanks

Comment: first of all: you should have ony one `settings.gradle` file, at the root directory level (root project).

Comment: you need to wrap your `buildAll` task definition in a `projectsEvaluated` lifecycle hook method, see https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle.html#org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle:projectsEvaluated(org.gradle.api.Action). indeed, when configuring root project, Gradle does not yet know about `assembleDebug` tasks from subprojects, as they have not been evaluated.